# How can I stop Visual Studio removing Office files from the solution automatically?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I've been developing a project for a while, and we have started a "documentation" folder  in the Visual Studio 2008 solution so that we can keep the developer documentation (and a few other useful files) in there (it's one of Visual Studio's solution folders, rather than a project).  We're also using the AnkhSVN plugin so these files get copied to Subversion.

However, every time I save any of the files, Visual Studio automatically removes it from the solution, so I have to add it back in,and then close Word again without saving.

I'd have thought this was a fairly easy problem to solve, but the past three weeks (and reading many spurious results on Google for almost every search query I can think of that might be relevant) seem to have proved me wrong.

Does anyone have any ideas how to stop this behaviour?

Comment: I would like to differ to the practice of keeping documentation in the solution itself.

Comment: To be honest it's because of using AnkhSVN, meaning that everything that goes in SVN has to go through VS. Normally I'd prefer that (if it's kept in SVN at all) we use a separate directory from the VS solution. But this is what the project manager requires, so I have to do it.

Comment: I am having the exact same problem. And it's 100% reproducible. Tempted to put out a bounty.

Comment: This seems to be the explanation, with a work-around:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469695/word-files-disappear-from-solution-items-in-vs2010

Comment: @LeeGrissom do you want to add that as an answer and I'll accept it as the right answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this still happens with VS2013, but for VS2010 here is a detailed explanation on the cause and a work-around:

- [Word files disappear from "Solution Items" in VS2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469695/word-files-disappear-from-solution-items-in-vs2010)

Comment: Haven't tried it in 2013 myself, either, but I'll give this a try next time I'm on the other project.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the files are removed and not just hidden?  I had a similar thing with non-code files.

- [Showing and Hiding Hidden Files in Visual Studio 2008](http://peterkellner.net/2007/12/31/visualstudioshowallfiles/)

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. This doesn't seem to affect non-Office files either, which is peculiar. The moment I add the file back in, VS wants to open it in Word or Excel, which is behaviour I've never seen before.

Comment: I should have mentioned these aren't in one of the actual projects, but at the top level of the solution...